# How to make a jQuery Horizontal Tab that loads the page once

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs

I want a jQuery horizontal tab pane (screenshot below) where clicking on a tab loads an external page in the div but where clicking on it after it is loaded does not load the page again.

There are 7 tabs `Wall`, `Latest`, `Discussion`, `Poll`, `Club Message`, `Create`.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2tTx.jpg]

A demo can be seen here http://www.web-shine.in/tabs/

I want the TAB to load the page once, and next time the user clicks on it, it should show the page from browser cache, not from the server.

What is the best way to code this?

Comment: We need your HTML, not just image of web page. Your JavaScript needs to be edited, to disable .click() event on current page and reenable it, when other tab is clicked. Without source, we cant help you more.

Comment: here is the code/demo, view it  http://www.web-shine.in/tabs/

Comment: I tested your given link, it works correctly.

Comment: @Deele -> It works, but not perfectly, i need to load the page once, if the Current time is X, you go to PAGE 1 it shows X, go to page 2 it shows X+Y, going back to PAGE 1 should display the X again, not X+Y+Z ! i dont want to load the page again and again !!!

Comment: No need to put "not answered" in the page title - questions without accepted answers on SO can be identified as such at a glance. (The number of answers counter will be white rather than yellow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var cache = {};

function loadTab(tabObj) {
    if(!tabObj || !tabObj.length){ return; }
    $(containerId).fadeOut(100);

    var target = tabObj.attr('href');

    if (cache[target] !== undefined) {
        $(containerId).html(cache[target]);
        $(containerId).slideDown('medium');
        $(containerId).fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $(containerId).load(tabObj.attr('href'), function()
        {
            cache[target] = $(containerId).html();
            $(containerId).slideDown('medium');
            $(containerId).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my work, your code worked exactly the way i wanted thnx :)          and thnx to all for replying and helping on this problem !!!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function.

Ex:

```
$("#foo").one("click", function() {
  alert("click can only be done once.");
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you are trying to cache the Ajax response so that subsequent Ajax requests that match the original Ajax options will return the cached response instead of making a new call then i highly recommend using this excellent jQuery plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajax-cache-response

Comment: Wouldn't this show the tab only once?? After the page has been loaded by AJAX, if the function is only executed once, then how will the tab change??

Comment: This will only make the tab clickable once so he can't click to reload again. This has nothing to do with showing or hiding. See example at http://jsfiddle.net/xM5E7/1/

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I'm just saying that the OP probably wants the tab to be clickable more than once, he just wants the tab page to be cached to save bandwidth...that's my guess...so maybe apply another click handler in the `.one()` function?

Comment: That doesn't make too much sense. What would be the purpose of clicking the tab again if it isn't used for loading content.

Comment: "want that TAB should load the page once, and next time the user clicks on it, it should show the page from browser cache, not from the server !" idk if that makes sense (from OP)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is put this sample inside an AJAX call:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation

Comment: Please elaborate on this by summarizing the linked text in the context of the question. If the link changes or breaks, this answer has no context or value.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your AJAX call in the "show" event of the tabs. This should only fire, when a tab is shown (i.e. when the selected tab changes).

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#event-show

Comment: Okay, I get it now. How about setting a global variable "isLoaded", which is false on init. When a user clicks a tab ("show" event), you check whether the var is false. If it is false, you load the content of all tabs and set the var to true.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry if i got it wrong but;

```
$('#tabs').tabs({cache: true});
```

It's enough.