# validate user input on keypress on textbox jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to code in jQuery so a user can not press dot "." key in a text box ?

i can code it in javascript like that, on each keypress the browser checks if a key is pressed, if it is dot then substring(0,len-1), but it flickers !
i want to completely block pressing the key !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work. It has not been cross-browser tested:

```
$("#theTextBox").keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val().indexOf('.') !== -1) {
        var newVal = $(this).val().replace('.', '');
        $(this).val(newVal);
    }
});
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cyVnG/)

EDIT: I think this is better:

```
function doItPlease() {
    if ($(this).val().indexOf('.') !== -1) {
        var newVal = $(this).val().replace('.', '');
        $(this).val(newVal);
    }
}

$("#theTextBox").bind("keydown keyup", doItPlease);
```

[**Try the less sucky solution here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cyVnG/1/)

EDIT (again): I favour the above solution, because I quite like the feedback aspect. That said, I think this is what you're after:

```
$("#theTextBox").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which != 190) {
        return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**Try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/cyVnG/2/)

Comment: The first solution breaks if you hold down '.'. The second solution cheats your cat if he/she happens to press it down.

Comment: yup, this one is better :) ,but still a little way to go

Comment: @karim79 can you help me in this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498851/horizontal-tab-to-load-page-once

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this plugin to prevent specific characters being entered: http://www.itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/

Also have a look at the validation plugin for general validation: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Alphanumeric breaks on Control+V event :(

Answer (score 1):

Use the excellent http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ form validation plugin.

All you need to do to validate is issue the options as a class name:

**HTML**

```
<input id="test" type="text" class="required email"/>
```

Adding `required` and `email` as a class will validate it as a required input that must be an email. Validation is done as you type.

**jQuery**

```
$('#test').validate()
```

The great thing about this plug-in is you can access the js file directly from Microsoft CDN so you don't' have to load it from your server. 
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.js